# Flutter dart, after IF statement can use object methods

Tags: flutter, dart, object, methods

Anyone can explain, why after IF statement can can not use object methods?

```
if(state is CurrentPlayerState){
  state.getPermanentStatsByTitle(); <- The method 'getPermanentStatsByTitle' isn't defined for the type 'PlayerState'.
}
```

**PlayerState** - is abstract and really not contain the method. But **CurrentPlayerState** has the method.

Comment: It could be as simple that the IDE doesn't understand the implicit cast that is made. So casting it explicitly before using the method might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it:

```
if(state is CurrentPlayerState){
  (state as CurrentPlayerState).getPermanentStatsByTitle();
}
```